# wc gzipped files?

Tags: linux, unix

I have a directory with both uncompressed and gzipped files and want to run `wc -l` on this directory. `wc` will provide a line count value for the compressed files which is not accurate (since it seems to count newlines in the gzipped version of the file). Is there a way to create a `zwc` script similar to `zgrep` that will detected the gzipped files and count the uncompressed lines?

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/135329/count-lines-in-a-compressed-file

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this *zwc* script:

```
#! /bin/bash --
for F in "$@"; do
  echo "$(zcat -f <"$F" | wc -l) $F"
done
```

Comment: It should be "echo "$(zcat -f <"$F" | wc -l) $F"

Answer (score 16):

You can use `zgrep` to count lines as well (or rather the beginning of lines)

```sh
zgrep -c ^ file.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

I use too "cat *file_name* | gzip -d | wc -l"